# Algorithm for labeling edges of a triangular mesh

Tags: algorithm, mesh, edge-detection, triangular, labeling

### Introduction

As part of a larger program (related to rendering of volumetric graphics), I have a small but tricky subproblem where an arbitrary (but finite) triangular 2D mesh needs to be labeled in a specific way. Already a while ago I wrote a solution (see below) which was good enough for the test meshes I had at the time, even though I realized that the approach will probably not work very well for every possible mesh that one could think of. Now I have finally encountered a mesh for which the present solution does not perform that well at all -- and it looks like I should come up with a totally different kind of an approach. Unfortunately, it seems that I am not really able to reset my lines of thinking, which is why I thought I'd ask here.

### The problem

Consider the picture below. (The colors are not part of the problem; I just added them to improve (?) the visualization. Also the varying edge width is a totally irrelevant artifact.)

[image]

For every triangle (e.g., the orange ABC and the green ABD), each of the three edges needs to be given one of two labels, say "0" or "1". There are just two requirements:

1. Not all the edges of a triangle can have the same label. In other words, for every triangle there must be two "0"s and one "1", *or* two "1"s and one "0".
2. If an edge is shared by two triangles, it must have the same label for both. In other words, if the edge AB in the picture is labeled "0" for the triangle ABC, it must be labeled "0" for ABD, too.

The mesh is a genuine 2D one, and it is finite: i.e., it does not wrap, and it has a well-defined outer border. Obviously, on the border it is quite easy to satisfy the requirements -- but it gets more difficult inside.

Intuitively, it looks like at least one solution should always exist, even though I cannot prove it. (Usually there are several -- any one of them is enough.)

### Current solution

My current solution is a really brute-force one (provided here just for completeness -- *feel free to skip this section*):

- Maintain four sets of triangles -- one for each possible count (0..3) of edges remaining to be labeled. In the beginning, every triangle is in the set where three edges remain to be labeled.
- For as long as there are triangles with non-labeled edges:
  Find the smallest non-zero number of unallocated edges for which there are still triangles left. In other words: at any given time, we try to minimize the number of triangles for which the labeling has been *partially* completed. The number of edges remaining will be anything between 1 and 3. Then, just pick one such triangle with this specific number of edges remaining to be allocated. For this triangle, do the following:

  - See if the labeling of any remaining edge is already imposed by the labeling of some other triangle. If so, assign the labels as implied by requirement #2 above.
  - If this results in a dead end (i.e., requirement #1 can no more be satisfied for the present triangle), then *start over the whole process from the very beginning*.
  - Allocate any remaining edges as follows:

    - If no edges have been labeled so far, assign the first one randomly.
    - When one edge already allocated, assign the second one so that it will have the opposite label.
    - When two edges allocated: if they have the same label, assign the third one to have the opposite label (obviously); if the two have different labels, assign the third one randomly.
  - Update the sets of triangles for the different counts of unallocated edges.
- If we ever get here, then we have a solution -- hooray!

Usually this approach finds a solution within just a couple of iterations, but recently I encountered a mesh for which the algorithm tends to terminate only after one or two *thousands* of retries... Which obviously suggests that there may be meshes for which it *never* terminates.

---

Now, I would love to have a deterministic algorithm that is guaranteed to always find a solution. Computational complexity is not that big an issue, because the meshes are not very large and the labeling basically only has to be done when a new mesh is loaded, which does not happen all the time -- so an algorithm with (for example) exponential complexity ought to be fine, as long as it works. (But of course: the more efficient, the better.)

Thank you for reading this far. Now, any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

---

### Edit: Results based on suggested solutions

Unfortunately, I cannot get [the approach suggested by Dialecticus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096005/algorithm-for-labeling-edges-of-a-triangular-mesh/4096189#4096189) to work. Maybe I did not get it right... Anyway, consider the following mesh, with the start point indicated by a green dot:
[image]
Let's zoom in a little bit...
[image]
Now, let's start the algorithm. After the first step, the labeling looks like this (red = "starred paths", blue = "ringed paths"):
[image]
So far so good. After the second step:
[image]
And the third:
[image]
... fourth:
[image]
But now we have a problem! Let's do one more round - but please pay attention on the triangle plotted in magenta:
[image]
According to my current implementation, all the edges of the magenta triangle are on a ring path, so they should be blue -- which effectively makes this a counterexample. Now maybe I got it wrong somehow... But in any case the two edges that are nearest to the start node obviously cannot be red; and if the third one is labeled red, then it seems that the solution does not really fit the idea anymore.

Btw, [here is the data used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z4wiqhtmw5kd1r/edgedata.txt). Each row represents one edge, and the columns are to be interpreted as follows:

1. Index of first node
2. Index of second node
3. *x* coordinate of first node
4. *y* coordinate of first node
5. *x* coordinate of second node
6. *y* coordinate of second node

The start node is the one having index 1.

---

I guess that next I should try [the method suggested by Rafał Dowgird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096005/algorithm-for-labeling-edges-of-a-triangular-mesh/4099045#4099045)... But perhaps I ought to do something completely different for a while :)

Comment: Very good question, but maybe better asked on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Pukku - just a heads up that the image links are dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you order the triangles so that for every triangle at most 2 of its neighbors precede it in the order, then you are set: just color them in this order. The condition guarantees that for each triangle being colored you will always have at least one uncolored edge whose color you can choose so that the condition is satisfied.

Such an order exists and can be constructed the following way:

1. Sort all of the vertices left-to-right, breaking ties by top-to-bottom order.
2. Sort the triangles by their last vertex in this order.
3. When several triangles share the same last vertex, break ties by sorting them clockwise.

Comment: Although such an order does exist, and can be used as suggested, the left-to-right-by-centers approach does not necessarily induce such an order.  For example, consider the triangle whose vertices are (0,1), (0,-1), and (10,0).  Make a second triangle by connecting the right edge to the point (-100,0).  Make a third by connecting the top edge to (-100, 20), and make a third by connecting the bottom edge to (-100, -20).  Although there are several competing notions of "center of triangle", I *think* that each notion should order the triangles contrary to your claim.

Comment: It seems to work! Thank you so much!!! I am accepting this answer for now -- if I ever come up with a counter-example, I'll surely be back :)

Comment: I do believe this will always work.  It's a very pretty strategy.

Comment: @Josephine: I think I've got a proof this always works, I'll put it here when I've got enough time.

Answer (score 2):

Given any node in the mesh the mesh can be viewed as set of concentric rings around this node (like spider's web). Give all edges that are not in the ring (starred paths) a value of 0, and give all edges that are in the ring (ringed paths) a value of 1. I can't prove it, but I'm certain you will get the correct labeling. Every triangle will have exactly one edge that is part of some ring.

Comment: This doesn't always work.  If you start with a nice triangulation of a sphere, embed it in the plane, then follow this strategy starting from the "north pole", it's possible for a triangle near the "south pole" to be the last of your rings, requiring 1's all the way around.

Comment: You are right, I had planar mesh in mind (if that's what it's called). OP mentioned "2D mesh" which led me to believe he's not modeling 3D structures.

Comment: Correct: the mesh is essentially planar. Thank you very much for the suggestion, Dialecticus - I am definitely going to try to implement it.

Comment: From a sphere triangulation you can build a planar one : take one of the triangle and make it grow big enough so that all the other can be flatten inside it. The counter-example from @Josephine is  valid.

Comment: But when transformation is done this big triangle stops being the elementary triangle. It turns into the border of the whole mesh and the labeling rule does not apply to it.

Comment: Although a solution always exists, and although Dialecticus' idea is very nice, it doesn't always succeed. It is possible for the "concentric rings" he describes to become concave. If, for example, one of Dialecticus' "rings" passes through the vertices A, B, C, D, E in order and makes a concave portion of the curve, then it is possible for the triangle ACE to be one of the triangles in the mesh, and also lie outside the ring. If so, each edge of the triangle ACE will get the label 0.

Comment: I agree that the solution does not always work -- see the edited question.

Comment: @Josephine, you're right, nice comment. I suppose that the algorithm must first choose the concave over convex subgraph, and then within the subgraph swap values of some edges until the labeling rule is fulfilled. Need to think it over a little.